# checking whether two types are alias templates to each other in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

When I defined

```
template <class T> struct A {};
template <class T> using B = A<T>;
```

B is just an alias of A. How to check that in compile time? I tried:

```
#include <type_traits>
template <template <class...> class T, template <class...> class U>
struct IsAlias: std::false_type {};

template <template <class...> class T> struct IsAlias<T, T>: std::true_type {
};

int main() {
  static_assert(IsAlias<A, B>(), "");                 // Error
  static_assert(IsAlias<B, B>(), "");                 // OK
  static_assert(std::is_same<A<int>, B<int> >(), ""); // OK
}
```

It doesn't work. Tested in g++4.8.1 and clang++3.3 with "-std=c++11"

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @filmor "main.cpp:12:3: error: static assertion failed"

Comment: `A` and `B` are distinct template-names. They always happen to produce identical types when instantiated with the same parameter list, but the compiler cannot take that into account.